# Summing over product of tensor elements and vector

Tags: python, pytorch, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to write a python code for a higher order (d=4) factorization machine that returns the scalar result y of

[image: Factorization machine for degree 4 problem]

Where x is  a vector of some length n, v is a vector of length n, w is an upper triangular matrix of size n by n, and t is a rank 4 tensor of size n by n by n by n. The easiest implementation is just for loops over each index:

```py
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    for j in range(0,len(x)):
        for k in range(0,len(x)):
            for l in range(0,len(x)):
                y += t[i,j,k,l] * x[i] * x[j] * x[k] * x[l]
```

The first two terms are easily calculated:

```py
y = u @ x + x @ v @ x.T
```

My question- is there a better way of calculating the sum over the tensor than a nested for-loop? (currently looking at possible solutions in pytorch)

Comment: I think `(t * x[:, None, None, None] * x[None, :, None, None] * x[None, None, :, None] * x[None, None, None, :]).sum()` will work.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a perfect fit for [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html):

```
>>> torch.einsum('ijkl,i,j,k,l->', t, *(x,)*4)
```

In expanded form, this looks like `torch.einsum('ijkl,i,j,k,l->', t, x, x, x, x)` and computes the value defined by your four `for` loops:

```
for i, j, k, l in cartesian_prod:
    y += t[i,j,k,l] * x[i] * x[j] * x[k] * x[l]
```

Where `cartesian_prod` is the cartesian product: `range(len(x))^4`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you swag2198

```
(c * x[:, None, None, None] * x[None, :, None, None] * x[None, None, :, None] * x[None, None, None, :]).sum()
```

Returns the same result as the for-loops when test on dummy values of x and t